# How to change "Shipping Calculator "field label on Cart Page - woocommerce?

Tags: php, pages, css, woocommerce-offtopic

I actually have two questions.

1) how do I change the label "shipping calculator" to say something else on my cart page?

2) How do I make the item text show up under shipping contents. Right now it is there but it is hidden or colored white for some reason? See images attached

Item text not showing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VeJW.jpg

With text highlighted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T33PT.jpg

Thanks for your time,
Reed

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'woocomerce_text_strings', 20, 3 );        
function woocomerce_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {            
       switch ( $translated_text ) {            
            case 'shipping calculator' :        
                $translated_text = __( 'Calculate Shipping', 'woocommerce' );        
                break;    
        }        
        return $translated_text;             
}
```